# Sorting the order of categories in navbar using Gatsby JS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a dynamic navbar that I implemented using graphql. I manage to get the categories by using `distinct` and setting the field to `frontmatter___category` then using `.map()`. However, graphql returns the categories in an alphabetical order but I want to sort their order. I am thinking of creating an `index.md` per category that could be used to sort them but I don't know how I could do that.

Using the distinct field, here is how I map through my categories and create the navbar (I'm using antd):

```
<Menu>
  {data[section]['distinct'].map((category) =>(
    <SubMenu 
      key={category} 
      title={category.replace('-', ' ')}
      style={{
        fontWeight: 700,
        maxWidth: 250,
      }}
    >
      {checkCategory(category)} //get the MD files that belongs to this category
    </SubMenu>
  ))}
</Menu>
```

Here is my query:

```
categoryA: allMdx(
  sort: {fields: frontmatter___order, order: ASC}
  filter: {frontmatter: {section: {eq: "categoryA"}}}
  ) {
    distinct(field: frontmatter___category)
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          category
          path
          title
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

This is my frontmatter, the order is for sorting the md file in the navbar:

```
---
title: item 1
path: /section1/categoryA/item1
category: categoryA
section: section1
order: 1
---
```

My folder structure is like this:

```
|---contents
|   |---section1
|   |   |---categoryA
|   |   |   |---item1.md
|   |   |---categoryB
|   |   |   |---item2.md
|   |   |---categoryC
|   |   |   |---item3.md
|   |   |---categoryD
|   |   |   |---item4.md
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right the sort order numbers are getting sorted as strings. In that case you could just add a trailing zero to the order field in the MD files. But that's a little hacky. Another option is to just sort the results in Javascript. I've just done a quick Google and from what I can see there is no GraphQL native way to do this...which is a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `sort` GraphQL option sorts alphabetically. In your case, if you want the default order just remove the following line:

```
  sort: {fields: frontmatter___order, order: ASC}
```

Leaving your query as:

```
categoryA: allMdx(
  filter: {frontmatter: {section: {eq: "categoryA"}}}
  ) {
    distinct(field: frontmatter___category)
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          category
          path
          title
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

This should return the categories in the fetched order.

Another option is using the JavaScript [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method before printing the categories somewhere. Something like:

```
let sortedData = props.data.categoryA.edges.node.sort((a, b) => a.frontmatter.order - b.frontmatter.order);
```

Applying your code. The idea relies on not using GraphQL sorting but JavaScript's.

```
let sortedData= data[section]['distinct'].sort((a, b) => a.frontmatter.order - b.frontmatter.order));
```

Then just loop through your `sortedData` in the same way.:

```
  {sortedData[section]['distinct'].map((category) =>(
    <SubMenu 
      key={category} 
      title={category.replace('-', ' ')}
      style={{
        fontWeight: 700,
        maxWidth: 250,
      }}
    >
      {checkCategory(category)} //get the MD files that belongs to this category
    </SubMenu>
  ))}
```

Comment: The sort in GraphQL is for setting the order of the MD files, so removing that wouldn't work, while the order is for sorting of the MD files. I'm not sure how I can implement your other suggestion but I edited my question to add how I map through my categories if that would help.

Comment: There are a few missing contexts but I've edited the question with a trial. The idea relies on not using GraphQL sorting in favor of JavaScript's: sort the data (using `sort()`, store that information in a variable, and loop through that variable instead of using `data[section]['distinct'].map`